# Как найти индекс максимального элемента списка*?

Tags: c#, list, max

Есть список

```
var lst = new List<double>();
lst.Add(123);
lst.Add(123);
lst.Add(2);
```

Пытаюсь получить индекс максимального элемента, однако не могу понять как возвратить последний максимальный элемент. На данный момент он говорит что максимальный элемент 0, что в принципе и правда, однако мне нужен максимальный последний индекс.

```
public int MaxIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
            using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty sequence");
                }
                int maxIndex = 0;
                T maxElement = iterator.Current;
                int index = 0;
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    index++;
                    T element = iterator.Current;
                    if (comparer.Compare(element, maxElement) > 0)
                    {
                        maxElement = element;
                        maxIndex = index;
                    }
                }
                return maxIndex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `comparer.Compare(element, maxElement) > 0` - замените > на >=, тогда индекс будет указывать на последний встретившийся максимальный элемент.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
...
lst.LastIndexOf(lst.Max());
```